# What are the roots and conjugates of a minimum polynomial?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory, minimal-polynomials

I have an exam coming up on coding theory stuff and I'm stumped on how to find the minimum polynomial. A study guide I was given is here: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~lomonaco/f14/653/handouts/StudyProbs653.pdf

Problem 3. on that page is what I'm looking at.
So we have a primitive element of $GF(2^6)$ $ξ$ such that: $1 + ξ + ξ^6$ = 0. They are trying to find the minimum polynomial $m_{36}(x)$ of $ξ^{36}$

They say the roots of $m_{36}(x)$ consist of $ξ^{36}$ and all its conjugates and lists the roots as $ξ^{36}$, $ξ^{9}$, $ξ^{18}$.

How exactly did they get these roots? They then say $ξ^{36}$ is of degree 3, i.e. $m_{36}(x)$ = $x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$. Not sure how they got this polynomial either. I checked the log/antilog table at the bottom of the page and it doesn't match up for me. Any tips on understanding this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any primitive element $\xi\in GF(p^n)$, its $n$ conjugates are $\xi^{p^0}, \xi^{p^1}, \dots, \xi^{p^{n-1}}$. Moreover, the minimal polynomial of $\xi$ is just the product
$$
(x - \xi^{p^0})(x - \xi^{p^1}) \cdots (x -\xi^{p^{n-1}}) = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (x - \xi^{p^i}).
$$
Any primitive element has (multiplicative) order $p^n-1$, that is, $\xi^{p^n-1} = 1$, and the nonzero elements of $GF(p^n)$ form a cyclic multiplicative group $\{1 = \xi^{0}, \xi^1, \xi^2, \dots, \xi^{p^n-2}\}$. Hence we can do exponent arithmetic modulo $p^n-1$.

These facts should allow you to do the desired calculations.

Comment: I think I get it. So I keep multiplying the power by 2? As in, $ξ^{36}$ becomes  $ξ^{72}$ which, since log/antilog table only goes up to 62 before it repeats, means $ξ^{72}$ is equal to $ξ^{9}$ correct? I understand now that the # of roots is the degree.

Comment: And if this was over GF(3), it would be multiplying the power by 3 each time?

Comment: Yes, everything you said is correct!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)

Comment: One more question. In the example, they picked $ξ^9$ to determine the unknown coefficients. Does it matter which root you use? I assume they just used that because it's the easiest one compute.

Comment: It doesn't matter which one. Note that the minimal polynomial of $\xi^{36}$ and all of its conjugates is the same!

Comment: Awesome, thanks!